# Move some (not all) users from one ASP.NET Membership database to another

Tags: database, asp.net-membership

Does anybody know if it is possible to move some (not all) users from one ASP.NET membership database to another? (for the purposes of migrating some users to another database on another machine, but not all).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in features dedicated for this purposes. But you can do this your self. For example you can use [Data Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833273.aspx#CompareDataOfTwoDatabases) form the DataDude. In words, this toll helps to move data between databases, so you do not need to do this row-by-row.